# Singular nouns ending with -isi (Masculine or Feminine?)

Tags: grammar, nouns, gender, plural

For preparation for my Italian grammar test tomorrow, I am going through content we've learnt, such as masculine and feminine determination rules. However, I've come up against a dilemma. I distinctly remember my teacher saying that words ending with -isi, like *crisi*, were feminine, so *la crisi*, and in plural form it would turn to *le crise*. However, after searching online, I couldn't find any examples of this. So, is this a proper rule, and are there any more examples of nouns falling under this category?

Comment: Welcome to ItalianSE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the plural of **la crisi** is **le crisi**. Le crise doesn't exist.

In Italian, some nouns and adjectives are ***invariant***, that is, they have the same form for singular and plural:

> il re ▶ i re
>
> la crisi ▶ le crisi
>
> la specie ▶ le specie

There are a lot of [different rules and examples](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/nomi-e-aggettivi-invariabili_(La-grammatica-italiana)/):

> • Nouns ending with an *accented vowel*:
>
> **le tribù, le città, i maragià, i caffè**
>
> Among these we obviously also have monosyllable nouns and adjectives:
>
> **i re, le maglie blu, i tè, gli gnu**
>
> • Some masculine nouns ending with *-a*, especially about exotic
>   animals:
>
> **i lama, i gorilla, i cobra, i cacatua**
>
> Also remind **i boia, i paria, i sosia, i vaglia**, whereas **pigiama** has
>   both the invariant form **i pigiama** and the normal form **i pigiami**.
>
> • Shortened nouns
>
> **le auto, le bici, le moto, i cinema**
>
> • Some feminine nouns ending with *-ie*
>
> **le barbarie, le serie, le specie, le congerie, le temperie**
>
> • Adjectives and feminine nouns ending with *-i*
>
> **numeri pari, squadre dispari, le ipotesi, le analisi, le nevrosi**
>
> • Nouns composed of two verbs or a verb and a feminine singular noun:
>
> **i saliscendi, i posacenere, i va e vieni, gli scioglilingua**
>
> • Some borrowed foreign nouns:
>
> **gli sport, gli chalet, i würstel, i toreador**
>
> • Some adjectives indicating colors:
>
> **stoffe amaranto, pareti lilla, lampade rosa, guanti viola, sfumature indaco**
>
> • The adjective *arrosto*
>
> **due polli arrosto**
>
> • Also in the sequence *color adjective + related noun*:
>
> **camicie verde bottiglia, copertine grigio topo**
>
> • Compound adjectives with the prefix *anti- + a noun*
>
> **prodotti anticellulite, sostanze antigelo**
>
> • Some compound adjectives, originally adverbial phrases, where the
>   second element is *-bene, -modo, -poco*
>
> **ragazze perbene, uomini ammodo, case dappoco**
>
> • The adjective *avvenire* ‘futuro’, coming from the adverbial phrase *a venire*
>
> **i mesi avvenire, le giornate avvenire.**

Comment: I cannot claim to know Italian better than the Treccani, but does anyone really write *a venire* as one word?

Comment: @DenisNardin I agree, I also found avvenire weird, I would always use a venire.

Comment: “Avvenire” as an adjective looks unusual to me too, but having checked that all the major contemporary vocabularies (Treccani, Zingarelli, De Mauro, Devoto-Oli, Sabatini-Coletti) record it unanimously, I must believe that it's me being under a misconception.

Comment: Why is no one voting this answer up? This is clearly the superior answer of the two...

Answer (score 3):

Words in -*si* are invariant, so the plural of *la crisi* is *le crisi*, not **le crise*.

There are more examples of this kind of noun [here](https://tinyurl.com/yb25ths7). ([archived](http://archive.is/Vhpf6))

Comment: Could you please add some examples from the link to the answer so that it's more complete?